# Punto de corte en regresión logística

Tags: python, scikit-learn

estoy intentando cambiar el punto de corte en una regresión logística con la librería de Scikit learn pero no veo la manera aun habiendo leído la documentación de la misma. En SPSS te da la opción de cambiar ese parámetro pero aquí no lo consigo. Pongo código del algoritmo . Alguna ayuda? Gracias

```html
X = np.array(dataS)
y = np.array(target)
X.shape
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
model = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X,y)
predictions = model.predict(X)
model.score(X,y)

validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)
name='Logistic Regression'
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=161, random_state=seed)
cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
print(msg)

predictions = model.predict(X_validation)
print(accuracy_score(Y_validation, predictions))

print(confusion_matrix(Y_validation, predictions))
print(classification_report(Y_validation, predictions))
```